How does a transformer choose the next word concretely?
I am quite new to the topic of transformers. In a lecture of mine, we defined transformers as sequence to sequence mappings, i.e. a transformer $\mathcal{T}$ takes $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$ and maps it to $\mathcal{T}(X) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$. Of course, under the hood there are transformer blocks, attention layers, etc.
It is my understanding that $n$ represents the size of the context window and $d$ is the size of the word embedding. For example, suppose we have the sentence 'Gras is' and we want to use an already trained transformer. I understand that something like this is happening now:
$$
\text{Gras is} \overset{embedding}{\longrightarrow}
\begin{pmatrix}
0.6 \\
0.8 \\
-0.2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0.78 \\
-0.03 \\
-1.03
\end{pmatrix}
\approx
\begin{pmatrix}
0.6 & 0.78\\
0.8 & -0.03\\
-0.2 & -1.03
\end{pmatrix}
\overset{\mathcal{T}}{\longrightarrow}
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
0.89 & -0.7\\
0.2 & 1.23\\
-0.1 & 0.24
\end{pmatrix}}_{=: A}
\overset{???}{\longrightarrow}
\text{Next word}.
$$
So we tokenise the words 'Gras' and 'is', embed each word in $\mathbb{R}^3$, apply the transformer and end up with a new $2 \times 3$ matrix. Hence the context window is $n = 2$ and the embedding dimension is $d = 3$.
Question: How is the next word chosen?
I know that the transformer now uses the output matrix to sample the next word, but how does the work concretely. Suppose we have an alphabet of length $500$ and each word gets a vector embedding, leaving us with vectors $v_1, \dots, v_{500} \in \mathbb{R}^3$.
Based on what information from the matrix $A$ do I choose the next vector $v_i$ for $i=1,\dots,500$? E.g. one could look which vector $v_i$ is closest (in Euclidean distance) from e.g. the second column from $A$. But how is it really done?
I know that my understanding and depiction of a transformer is very basic, but I would like to understand how the next token is generated. I would be happy if someone could shed some light onto this. And feel free to comment on my understanding of a transformer in general if there is something completely wrong.
Thanks in advance!

A linear layer followed by Softmax is applied to the transformer output to get the probabilities for all tokens in the vocabulary, and then the next token/word is chosen based on these probabilities.
Refer to the Fig 1. of the Transformer paper by Vaswani et al. (2017)
